# How to print values of a column from the log output

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I would like to get all values under a column. Here is the example of my log output

> **Name,   Company,  City,  Country**
>
> **Nik**,     Apple,  **NY**,    USA
>
> **DAS**,   Facebook,     **DAll**,  USA
>
> **John**,   Twitter,   **Sydney**,  AUS

I want to print all the city names

**City**

NY

DALL

Sydney

**Name,   Company,  City,  Country** row is headings. I need output of City

Comment: **cut -d' ' -f 2 ./outputfile.txt** worked and now i'm able to print cities column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this with either a cut command or an awk command

with cut

```
cat 1.txt | cut -d, -f3  
City
NY
DAll
Sydney
```

where -d tells the delimiter and -f tells which field you would like to extract.

with awk

```
cat 1.txt | awk -F, '{print $3}'
City
NY
DAll
Sydney
```

-F specifies the delimiter as a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values in each record are separated by a comma and a space, you can split the line up with `string`'s `split` method.  Just specify how you'd like to split the string and you're off to the races.

```
records = []
with open('log.txt', 'r') as log_file:
    for line in log_file:
        name, company, city, country = line.split(', ')
        print(city)
        records.append((name, company, city, country))
```

If your log file is formatted in a more complicated fashion, you could look into using some simple pattern matching, regular expressions, or a proper log parsing library.

If you need to print out each of the unique city names rather than every one encountered, you could store them in a set:

```
cities = set()
with open('log.txt', 'r') as log_file:
    for line in log_file:
        name, company, city, country = line.split(', ')
        print(city)
        cities.add(city)
```

Comment: Oh yeah they are separated by comma and space

Comment: I updated my answer to better reflect what you're looking for and to present another approaches.

Comment: Got this error **cities.sh: line 2: CITIES: command not found
cities.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
cities.sh: line 3: `with open('log.txt', 'r') as log_file:'**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I answered from the perspective of a python script rather than a shell script.